# Visual Studio fails to deploy report to MSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

Visual Studio fails to deploy reports or data sources on remote MSRS instance. Error message is

> Unable to connect to the remote server.

The server is up and running and `TargetServerURL` property of the project points to correct url which works in the browser.

I googled around but and found a few forum threads discussing the same issue but none of them had any relevant resolution.

I am using `VS2008` and `MSRS 2008`.

Has anyone seen this before? Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

This was happening to me a couple of weeks ago.

Be sure the TargetServerURL is `http://server/ReportServer/` and not `http://server/Reports/`

There is a different URL used for the web services portion of reporting services (publishing/viewing/editing reports programmatically) and the visual UI where you can go in and browse the folders, etc.

Comment: I too struggled with this for a day!  The quirk I found too is that with a named instance of SQL Server 2008, the TargetServerURL is http://server/ReportServer_InstanceName, NOT http://server/Reports_InstanceName

Answer (score 2):

Nice Catch.  In my case, it was the last forward slash missing (`"http://server/ReportServer"` instead of `"http://server/ReportServer/`).  Also check if SecureConnectionLevel key (found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config`) to see if the Value is set to `"0"`.

Comment: I've been looking the solution for 2 days, only your method is working to me! Thanks.